# Learnable scalar weight in PyTorch and guarantee the sum of scalars is 1

Tags: pytorch, average, weighted, scalar

I have code like this:

```
class MyModule(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, channel, reduction=16, n_segment=8):
        super(MyModule, self).__init__()
        self.channel = channel
        self.reduction = reduction
        self.n_segment = n_segment
        
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.channel, out_channels=self.channel//self.reduction, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.channel, out_channels=self.channel//self.reduction, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.channel, out_channels=self.channel//self.reduction, kernel_size=1, bias=False)
        #whatever

        # learnable weight
        self.W_1 = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1), requires_grad=True)
        self.W_2 = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1), requires_grad=True)
        self.W_3 = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1), requires_grad=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        
        # whatever
        
        ## branch1                
        bottleneck_1 = self.conv1(x)
        
        ## branch2
        bottleneck_2 = self.conv2(x)
        
        ## branch3                
        bottleneck_3 = self.conv3(x)
        
        ## summation
        output = self.avg_pool(self.W_1*bottleneck_1 + 
                          self.W_2*bottleneck_2 + 
                          self.W_3*bottleneck_3) 
        
        return output
```

As you see, 3 learnable scalars (`W_1`, `W_2`, and `W_3`) are used for weighting purpose. But, this approach will not guarantee that the sum of those scalars is 1. How to make the summation of my learnable scalars equals to 1 in Pytorch? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
    ## summation
    WSum = self.W_1 + self.W_2 + self.W_3
    output = self.avg_pool( self.W_1/WSum *bottleneck_1 + 
                            self.W_2/WSum *bottleneck_2 + 
                            self.W_3/WSum *bottleneck_3)
```

Also, one can use distributivity law:

```
    output = self.avg_pool(self.W_1*bottleneck_1 + 
                      self.W_2*bottleneck_2 + 
                      self.W_3*bottleneck_3) /WSum
```

Comment: You mean: 
`output = self.avg_pool((self.W_1*bottleneck_1 + 
                      self.W_2*bottleneck_2 + 
                      self.W_3*bottleneck_3) /WSum)`
?

Comment: This will work too, but I have mean what I have written, - `avg_pool` commutes with `* Const` as well.

Comment: hi @alexey, when I print `WSum`, it prints repeating value? why no updating?

Comment: You mean, during training? What about `self.W_1, 2, 3`?

Comment: We are not want `WSum`==1, we are want `self.W_1/WSum + self.W_2/WSum + self.W_3/WSum`==1